# Is there any method same as gcm to be used for desktop application?

Tags: java

I want to make one desktop application for our college so that it can be use in the way so that when we want to send update about the college fest it can be directly reached to all the person who have the desktop application in java.

For android we have the GCM concept. Is there any method for the desktop application also?

I do not want to use polling here .... So please tell me any suitable method how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not without running a server of your own. GCM is a particular service that Google runs free of charge to encourage developers to use the Android platform, and it works by having every Android device make a TCP connection to Google and keep it open all the time waiting for incoming messages. You'd have to have your own similar server.

You could use a JMS publish/subscribe topic, but in this case, it is almost certainly a better idea to let the client poll for updates in JSON or RSS format. Is there a specific reason you don't want to poll?

Comment: No, sir i was thinking it will use internet connection every minute .... will it be a good method...?

Comment: Is dropbox or any other application also using polling?